# Can you rename an unused thrift field and change its type

Tags: thrift, thrift-protocol

Is it safe to rename an unused thrift field and also change its type. The APIs are still under development and not invoked by clients yet.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, because you can of course change unreleased stuff as often and as much as you want.
2. Even if you published the API, renaming is generally safe, except for service and service method names. For more info, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882370/is-safe-to-rename-a-field-in-thrift-idl).

Comment: If the thrift file has already been published but the API is still in development, would it be safe to change the type too?

Comment: When it is under development, so its kind of a pre-release version, right? Change it and communicate there were some breaking changes for technical reasons. This generally applies to any kind of API or UI or whatever.